# Plotting dataframe with different scale values in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, feature-scaling

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Date': [1930, 1931, 1932, 1933,1934],
'Income': [2300000, 5698907, 5976753, 6086762, 6577780],
'Age': [22, 45, 35, 40, 28],
'Weight': [0.01, 0.003, 0.04, 0.08, 0.07]
})
```

Each variable has different scale values. I want to plot the varibales on 1 graph but due to the scale difference of the varibales i can only see the income line. I plotted using

```
df.plot(figsize=(20,10), linewidth=5, fontsize = 20);
```

I decided to feature scale based on what i found online so i did the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
df = scaler.fit_transform(df)
```

I then tried to plot the dataframe after the feature scalling and it gave the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. The aim is to plot all the variables on 1 graph.

Comment: What do/don't you understand from that error message? Speaking of, please provide the **entire** error traceback/message. Also, the code snippets you shared appear to be out of order, is that the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need create new `DataFrame`, because `fit_transform` return `2d numpy array`:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()

df = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
df.plot(figsize=(20,10), linewidth=5, fontsize = 20)
```

Comment: this worked. is there also a way i can pick which columns i want to plot?

Comment: @Tamarie - Yes, use list like `df[['Age','Income']].plot(figsize=(20,10), linewidth=5, fontsize = 20)`